# Bayes Rule, Probability, determine whether dependant or independant

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I need to determine whether or not x and y are independent from each other, using the data supplied below.  I think the solution should use bayes rule/product rule/some independence rule.  I just can't see how to determine independence/dependence.

```
X=0
Y=0
P(X=0,Y=0) = 0.15

X=0
Y=1
P(X=0,Y=1) = 0.20

X=1
Y=0
P(X=1,Y=0) = 0.35

X=1
Y=1
P(X=1,Y=1) = 0.30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It is enough to check whether or not $$P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1)P(Y=1) \\= [P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)]\times [P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=1)]$$

Comment: So that should prove independence or dependence?  I'm not sure I follow how exactly.  Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: well, compute [P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)]×[P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=1)] and you will know.

Comment: [P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)]×[P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=1)] = 0.325 and since 0.325 != 0.3 it shows they're independent?

If that's right I probably just need to stare at you're hint a bit longer till the light bulb goes off in my head.

Comment: This is it :) this is just $P(X=1) = \sum_y P(X=1,Y=y)$, nothing fancy.